# How can I disperse amcl particles in specific area?

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using `amcl`'s `global_localization` service. I have a big map and it has a lot of same shapes. `amcl` is getting confused easiliy. How can I disperse particles on specific local area?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230641/how-can-i-disperse-amcl-particles-in-specific-area?/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2016-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of `global_localization`, I'm using publishing to `/initialpose` topic method in my custom package. Now I can set covariance matrix to disperse particles in specific area.    `X_DEVIATION_WEIGHT`, `Y_DEVIATION_WEIGHT` and `YAW_DEVIATION_WEIGHT` parameters are globally declared;

```
bool publishToInitialPose(geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped msg, ros::Publisher publisher, bool last_publish = false)
{
    msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    msg.header.frame_id = "/" + NAMESPACE + "/map";
    msg.pose.pose.position.x = POS_X;
    msg.pose.pose.position.y = POS_Y;

    msg.pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    msg.pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    msg.pose.pose.orientation.z = ORI_Z;
    msg.pose.pose.orientation.w = ORI_W;

    msg.pose.covariance[0] = X_DEVIATION_WEIGHT; 
    msg.pose.covariance[7] = Y_DEVIATION_WEIGHT; 
    msg.pose.covariance[35] = YAW_DEVIATION_WEIGHT; 
    publisher.publish( msg );
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2